# A catch-all route with Web API and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC and Web API.
I need the following mapping:

```
http://mysite/     => Welcome page (MVC)
http://mysite/Help => Help page (MVC)
http://mysite/anything_else_here => Web API Search with "anything_else_here" param
```

I use the following bindings:

```
// RouteConfig.cs, MVC routing        
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                 action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

and

```
//WebApiConfig.cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CatchAll",
            routeTemplate: "{q}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "GetGeneric" },
            constraints: new  { q = @"\S+" }
```

This config works fine for all queries EXCEPT for those where there is a percentage mark (used for space encoding).

E.g. queries like

```
http://mysite/shop
http://mysite/get+discount
http://mysite/redeem+code
```

work fine, but

```
http://mysite/shopping%20experience
http://mysite/get%20discount
http://mysite/redeem%20code
```

don't. Instead, I get an error 404 "The resource cannot be found".

Any ideas how I can catch these queries?

The constrain "\S+" does match the percentage mark.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is by design. Your contraints are tested, but only after decoding the part of the URL that fits the parameter. Your `%20` is actually a space.

Your plus sign is not an encoded character and gets treated literally, so it matches the 'non-whitespace' class of the constraint expression.

Which begs the question: why do you have a constraint on that route?

Comment: I need this contrain to allow the empty route (nothing supplied at all) to be intercepted by ASP.NET MVC route dispatcher and show the me a rendered view rather than calling a WebAPI controller.

Comment: The convention is to prefix all of the Web API stuff with "/api", so that it would be a lot harder to confuse routing issues between them.

Comment: Yes, I know this convention. The problem is that the web application serves as proxy for an enterprise application I cannot change. This enterprise application sends a request in the form `http://endpoint/parameterstring`. My web application which is hosted on `http://endpoint/` parses the parameter string and returns the expected data back to this application, mimicking the original (no longer available) service. Hence I can't rely on any convention in the route. If no parameter string is supplied I return a help page for the user with explanation about this proxy service.